# Build using docker-compose and run app and mongo using docker run

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file in below format

```
services:
  production-api:
    build: .
    environment:
      - MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/productiondb
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
        - mongodb   
        # condition: service_healthy

  mongodb:
    # user: node
    image: mongo
    # volumes:
    #   - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    # healthcheck:
    #   test: echo 'db.runCommand("ping").ok' | mongo mongo:27017/productiondb --quiet 1
    #   interval: 10s
    #   timeout: 10s
    #   retries: 5
```

and docker-compose.prod.yml

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  production-api:
    container_name: "production"
    command: yarn start
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
```

How do I build using docker-compose -f and run both mongo and production using docker run?

Comment: Why not build and run? Else you'd need to publish the built images somewhere and then use those... Maybe explain a bit better your intent?

Comment: I want docker run options like --restart on failure etc

Comment: You don't have any particularly special build configuration in this `docker-compose.yml` file, so if you want to use `docker run` to start the containers, you can `docker build` the images like normal.  The [Compose YAML format](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) does support pretty much all of the `docker run` options (including [`restart:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart)), though.

Comment: yeah this is pretty basic atm but in future if I want to use docker swarm is docker-compose compatible with docker swarm?

Comment: anyways thanks I didn't know about docker-compose containing restart policy too will look at docker-compose only for production. Cheers!